# Another interesting integral related to the Omega constant

Tags: numerical-methods, lambert-w

Another interesting integral related to the Omega constant is the following
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{1 + 2\cos x + x \sin x}{1 + 2x \sin x + x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{1 + \Omega}.$$
Here $\Omega = {\rm W}_0(1) = 0.56714329\ldots$ is the Omega constant while ${\rm W}_0(x)$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W function. A similar interesting integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function).

When attempting to check the above answer numerically, Mathematica 9.0 gives $2.0101 \pm 0.0005$ (with a complaint about failure to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections...) compared to the exact answer of $2.004662032\ldots$

Plotting the integrand two observations can be made: (i) it tends to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$, and (ii) for $x$ greater than about 3 it is highly oscillatory with the amplitude of the oscillations tending to zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Given this, what would be the best way to evaluate the integral numerically if an accuracy of say $10^{-9}$ is needed? This accuracy should be achieved in a "reasonable" amount of time.

Comment: Mathematica can be coaxed into producing a numerical result with an error of $\approx 2.5 \times 10^{-8}$ with the command `NIntegrate[(1+2 Cos[x]+x Sin[x])/(1+2 x Sin[x]+x^2),{x,0,3000},WorkingPrecision->15,MaxRecursion->1000,MinRecursion->500,MaxPoints->40000]+NIntegrate[Sin[x]/x,{x,3000,\[Infinity]},WorkingPrecision->20,MaxRecursion->300,MinRecursion->100]`.  Some of these parameters are probably overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $$F(x) = \frac{1 + 2\cos x + x \sin x}{1 + 2x \sin x + x^2}.$$  Our aim is to compute $$I = \int_0^\infty F(x) ~ dx.$$   Using numerical quadrature specifically designed for oscillatory functions – [`quadosc`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html#oscillatory-quadrature-quadosc), part of [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/), in Python 2.7 – I get 50 decimal digits of accuracy in ~34 seconds:

```
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> import time
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> mp.pretty = True
>>> F = lambda x: (1+2*cos(x)+x*sin(x))/(1+2*x*sin(x)+x*x)
>>> t=time.time(); I=quadosc(F, [0,inf], period=2*pi); elapsed=time.time()-t;
>>> I
2.0046620323839787916115494152293765801902060137759
>>> elapsed
33.79676699638367
```

Compare with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F(1%2Blambertw(0,1))), or with `mpmath`:

```
>>> +pi/(1 + lambertw(1, 0))
2.0046620323839787916115494152293765801902060137759
```

---

What's the underlying math here?  In Section 1, I'll write my understanding of the `quadosc` function, as it applies to a function $$f(x) = g(x) \cos(\omega x + \phi),$$ where $g(x)$ is “slowly decaying.”  In Section 2, I'll outline some of the important ideas / give a non-rigorous explanation of how `quadosc` works for $F(x)$—**the “tl;dr” version is that $F(x)$ decays asymptotically and its zeros “asymptotically agree” with $\sin x$.**

## 1. `quadosc` for product of slowly-decaying function and sine wave

Suppose $f(x) = g(x) \cos(\omega x + \phi)$ for some slowly-decaying function $g(x)$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $\phi=0$.  In this case, [`quadosc`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html) will break the integral $$I = \int_0^\infty f(x) ~ dx$$ into half-periods: $$I = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \int_{k(2\pi/\omega)/2}^{(k+1)(2\pi/\omega)/2} f(x) ~ dx. \tag{*}$$  In other words, it will compute the integral on $[0,\pi/\omega]$, $[\pi/\omega,2\pi/\omega]$, $[2\pi/\omega,3\pi/\omega]$, $[3\pi/\omega,4\pi/\omega]$, etc.  (From [the source code](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py), it looks like `quadosc` uses [Gauss–Legendre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature) on each subinterval.)

The resulting series (*) is an alternating series!  Therefore, `nsum` – the `mpmath` function for numerically approximating infinite series – is called.  According to [its documentation](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/sums_limits.html), by default, `nsum` attemps to compute the sum two different ways – [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation), or [Shanks transfomation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation), which are both [sequence/series acceleration methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration).

Presumably both of these components – numerical integration on each subinterval, and numerical series summation – are done until the desired digits of precision (`mp.dps = 50`, where [`dps = decimal digits of precision`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html#setting-the-precision)) are satisfied.

## 2. `quadosc` for $F(x)$

Why does `quadosc` work for $\int_0^\infty F(x) ~ dx$?  Because $F(x)$ asymptotically decays, **and because its zeros “asymptotically agree” with $\sin(x)$**, in the sense that “*the positive roots $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of $F(x)$ (where $x_n < x_{n+1}$) satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n\pi - x_n) = 0$.*”

How?  I'll make two claims, and outline the important ideas that (I predict) could be used to derive a rigorous proof.  (1) The roots of $1+2\cos x + x\sin x = 0$ “asymptotically agree” with the roots of $1 + x\sin x  = 0$.  (2) The roots of $1+ x \sin x  = 0$ “asymptotically agree” with the roots of $\sin x  = 0$

**Important ideas for (1):**  Invoking the asymptotic series of $\sqrt{4+x^2}$ and $\arctan(x/2)$ – computed with Wolfram Alpha [[1]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotic+series+for+sqrt(4%2Bx%5E2)), [[2]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotic+series+for+arctan(x%2F2)) – we have 
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4+x^2} &\sim x + \frac2x - \frac{2}{x^3} + \frac{4}{x^5} + O(x^{-7}) \\
\arctan\frac x2 &\sim \frac\pi2 - \frac2x + \frac{8}{3x^3} - \frac{32}{5x^5} + O(x^{-7})
\end{align*}
Therefore, the numerator of $F(x)$ – which determines the roots of $F(x)$ – satisfies 
\begin{align*}
1+2\cos(x) + x\sin(x) &= 1 + \sqrt{4+x^2}\cos\left(x - \arctan\frac{x}{2}\right) \\
&\sim 1 + \left(x + \frac2x + O(x^{-3})\right) \cos\left( x - \frac\pi2 + \frac2x + O(x^{-3}) \right).
\end{align*}
Dropping the $x^{-1}$ and higher-order terms, and recalling $\cos(x - \frac\pi2) = \sin x$, $$ 1+2\cos(x) + x\sin(x) \sim 1 + x\sin(x).$$  As $x\to\infty$, the difference between $1+2\cos(x) + x\sin(x)$ and $1 + x\sin(x)$ will vanish, which implies that their roots will asymptotically agree, as claimed.

**Important ideas for (2):**  Note that $$1 + x\sin x = 0 \iff \frac1x + \sin x = 0 \quad (\text{assuming } x\not=0).$$  Clearly the difference between $\frac1x + \sin x$ and $\sin x$ will vanish in the limit $x\to\infty$, which implies that their roots will asymptotically agree, as claimed.