# Definite integrals with interesting results

Tags: integration, soft-question, definite-integrals

I just stumbled across the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx}=\sqrt{\pi}$. This intrigued my already-existing interest in integrals. It made me wonder, are there other integrals with crazy results?

Comment: Could you please be more specific with what kind of integrals you're looking for?

Comment: @teadawg1337 , integrals with unexpected results or integrals with just overall interesting results.

Comment: You should look for a course in complex analysis!

Comment: See: the highly voted questions with the relevant tag(s).

Comment: If you mean "other integrals where $\pi$ shows up for no apparent reason" - yes, definitely, that's part of $\pi$'s job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_{\mathbf{R}}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\pi$$
and 
$$\frac{22}{7} - \pi = \int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^4}{1+x^2}dx.$$

Comment: Actually, $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{e^{itx}}{1+x^2} dx = e^{-|t|}\pi$ for any $t\in \mathbb R$. Note that the integrand is complex but the answer is real..

Answer (score 12):

[One](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055468/integral-int-infty-infty-fracdxexx12-pi2/1055598#1055598) I just evaluated

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(e^x+x+1)^2+\pi^2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

or [the ultimate insanity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1/565626#565626)...

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\log\left(\frac{2\,x^2+2\,x+1}{2\,x^2-2\,x+1}\right) = 4 \pi \operatorname{arccot}{\sqrt{\phi}} $$

where $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 12):

This one, which is another version of your integral$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\left(x+ \tan x \right)^2} \mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi},$$
or this strange family
$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle  \int_0^{1} \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {\ddots + \cfrac 1 { 1 + \psi (\left\{1/x\right\}+1)}}}}  
 \mathrm{d}x 
& = \dfrac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n}} 
- \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{F_{n}^2}
\ln \left( \dfrac{F_{n+2}-F_{n}\gamma}{F_{n+1}-F_{n}\gamma} \right),\\\\
\end{align}
$$ 
where  $\left\{x\right\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the **fractional part** of $x$,  $\gamma$ is the Euler constant, $F_{n}$ are the Fibonacci numbers, $\psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$ is the digamma function and where the continued fraction has $n$ horizontal bars.

Comment: Okay. This family what you've created. Not bad. +1.

Comment: @user153012 Thank you.

Comment: Could you share more on how to evaluate the interesting family of integrals that you mentioned?

Comment: @Lucian Yes. Maybe, you could ask a related question so I would have more room than the one for this comment? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the site-rules explicitly allow and even encourage users to ask-and-answer their own questions.

Comment: @Lucian It is done here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060107/a-family-of-fractional-part-integrals-with-the-digamma-function  . Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

> ${\tt\mbox{Sophomore's Dream}}$: Discovered by *Johann Bernoulli* in 1697 !!!.

$$
\int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}n^{-n}
$$

Answer (score 9):

$\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty}\cos(x^2)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$

Math.stackexchange is full of such beautiful formulae.

Comment: but there seems to be room for more...

Answer (score 9):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\exp\Big(-\sqrt[n]x\Big)dx&=n!
\\
\\
\int_0^1\Big(1-\sqrt[n]x\Big)^mdx&={m+n\choose n}^{-1}={m+n\choose m}^{-1}
\\
\\
\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-\sqrt[n]x\Big)dx&=-H_n
\\
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Big(1-\sqrt[n]x\Big)&=-\ln x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

[$$\large\int_{-\infty}^\infty\, \frac{1}{1+(x+\tan x)^2}\, dx= \pi
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1015462/146687)

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}\ dx=4$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}\ dx=2$$

Answer (score 5):

Well I think $$\displaystyle \begin{align*} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \theta \log^{3} (\tan\theta) \, d\theta &= \frac{7 \pi^{2}}{32} \zeta (3) + \frac{93}{16} \zeta (5). \end{align*}$$

is pretty interesting.