# How to calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(\exp(x)- x)^2 + \pi^2} = \frac{1}{1 + W(1)}$

Tags: definite-integrals

On [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OmegaConstant.html) one finds without proof the integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(\exp(x) - x)^2 + \pi^2} = \frac{1}{1 + W(1)}$$

where $W$ denotes the Lambert W function. How can one show this? The link given on Mathworld is broken.

Comment: If you refer to Moll's article, you may have a look at [this](http://www.experimentalmath.info/maa-course/Moll-MAA.pdf). Unfortunately, it has no proof.

Comment: The answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function

Comment: @LordSoth Oh, thank you.

Comment: @user111187 With the same approach, you may generalize this result to $$I(\alpha)= \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\displaystyle \frac{1}{(e^x-x+\alpha+\ln \alpha)^2+\pi^2}= \displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha+1}, \quad \alpha > 0. $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just an application of the residue theorem. Take $\gamma_R$ as the union of the path that goes straight from $-R$ to $R$ and the semicircle that goes from $R$ to $-R$, counter-clockwise oriented. We have:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(\exp(x)-x)^2+\pi^2}=\lim_{R\to +\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\cdot\sum_{\xi\in S_R}\operatorname{Res}(f(z),z=\xi)$$
where $f(z)=\frac{1}{(\exp(z)-z)^2+\pi^2}$ and $S_R$ is the set of the zeroes of $(\exp(z)-z)^2+\pi^2$ having positive imaginary part and modulus bounded by $R$. For any $R$ big enough, $S_R$ is made of one element only, namely the solution of:
$$ \exp(z)-z = -i\pi,$$
that is:
$$\xi = i\pi - W(1).$$
The residue theorem hence gives:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(\exp(x)-x)^2+\pi^2} = \frac{1}{1+W(1)}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Why would $S_R$ be made of one element only for $R$ big enough? Aren't there infinitely many zeroes of $(e^x-x)^2+\pi^2$ in the upper half-plane, arbitrarily far away from $0$?

Comment: @Nilknarf: indeed this old answer of mine is inaccurate, but there is a cancellation of residues which allows to prove that the only residue which really matters is the residue at $i\pi-W(1)$, as claimed here. For a fixed proof, have a look at robjohn's solution to the linked question.

Comment: Okay, thank you and sorry to bother you!