# Proving $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{(e^x-x)^2+\pi ^2}dx=\frac{1}{e^{-e^{-e^{-e..}}}+1}$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{1}{(e^x-x)^2+\pi ^2}dx=\frac{1}{e^{-e^{-e^{-e..}}}+1}$$
I saw this integral in a mathematical book but I don't know how to find this result.

Comment: Numerically, this does not seem to be correct. I found $0.638104$

Comment: What book did you find this in?

Comment: The integral is Adamchik's Integral. You may see detailed solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function/207639#207639) and my blog entry [here](http://zacatzontli.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/adamchiks-integral-omega-constant/)

Comment: You changed the rhs, so I don't say anything (except that I don't know how to compute the rhs with sufficient accuracy). It would be good to know the book. Happy New Year !!

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I would bet this is a duplicate. I remember a robjohn's solution, with the residue theorem, of a similar integral, giving a value of the Lambert W function as answer - found. Voting for closing as a duplicate.

Comment: See my [answer](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic496.html) under username mathematics.