# Relationship Between Integrals for Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I am working trying to integrate this function...

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-x}}{2 \left(1-\lambda  \left(1-e^{-x} (x+1)\right)\right)} \, dx$$

but I can't find a way to do it. However, a similar one does...

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x e^{-x}}{2 \left(1-\lambda  \left(1-e^{-x} (x+1)\right)\right)} \, dx = \frac{-\log (1-\lambda)}{2 \lambda }$$

Is there any way to use the second result to integrate the first?

Comment: How did you arrive at the complex value of the second integral? I don't see a reason why $i$ should appear in there ...

Comment: I used Maple to compute that

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the integrand is real and you are integrating over a real interval, why should there be something complex in the result? Or is your $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Ok - you are correct - you don't need that value - I removed the complex component

Comment: @PMF I am almost certain that the answer is $\frac{1}{2-2\lambda}$. But I haven't found a way to prove it yet.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss I tried numerically evaluation the integral using your equation and the answer seems off a bit...With $\lambda$ = 0.5, numerically, your answer gives 1.0 - numerically, I get 0.712686

Comment: @PMF Maple gives 1.0 exactly for $\lambda = .5$.

Comment: @ PMF
g := proc (y) options operator, arrow; int(exp(-x)/(2-2*y(1-exp(-x)*(x+1))), x = 0 .. infinity) end proc;

g(1/2);
                               1

Comment: Hmm..I plugged that formula into my system and I got 0.712686...Not sure what is going on

Comment: Note that $$(e^{-x} (1 + x))' = -xe^{-x}$$

Comment: This shows the second integral is logarithmic.

Comment: This may sound "crazy"...But compared to the 1st integral, it seems like the 2nd integral takes an "expectation" of the first. Maybe there is  way using something like "iterated expectations" (or something like that) to recover the first integral from the second...

Comment: might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function/207639#207639

Comment: @GaussTheBauss
this is what WA finds for $\lambda=1/2$
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5BExp%5B-x%5D%2F(1%2BExp%5B-x%5D(x%2B1)),%7Bx,0,10000%7D%5D

Comment: I get that value as well: 0.587137 for $\lambda = 0.5$

Comment: @tired - thanks for the reference - I'll check that out...