# How can we show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{ke^x\pm1\over \pi^2+(e^x-x+1)^2}\cdot{(e^x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(e^x+x+1)^2}\cdot 2x \,\mathrm dx=k?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Motivated by this [paper](http://www.experimentalmath.info/maa-course/Moll-MAA.pdf).

**Conjecture:**

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{ke^x\pm1\over \pi^2+(e^x-x+1)^2}\cdot{(e^x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(e^x+x+1)^2}\cdot 2x \,\mathrm dx=k,\tag1$$
>   where $k$ is a real number.

**Making an attempt:**

$u=e^x+1\implies \,\mathrm du=e^x\,\mathrm dx$ and let $k=1$ for simplification, then (1) becomes

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}{u^3\over \pi^2+(u-x)^2}\cdot{\ln(u-1)\over \pi^2+(u+x)^2}\cdot{2\mathrm du\over u-1}.\tag2$$

I have no idea where to go from here! I don't think substitution work here, probably using contour integration.

**How can we prove (1)?**

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function

Comment: how do you came up with this conjecture? (+1)

Comment: Btw. what is the meaning of the $\pm$ symbol? both integrals give the same value?

Comment: Most likely the integral is given by the residue at $x=i \pi $ plus/minus the residue at $x=\infty$. Unluckily i don't have the time to dig in deeper (especially one has to show that all other residue contributions vanish) but maybe someone can take it from here

Comment: Numerically the cancelations defintily happens, so this is the way to go

Comment: Yes @tired both integrals gave the same result

Comment: @tired, I would appreciate it if you could post your method. How to exploit the residue at infinity ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai i will try to post something the next days but i can't  promise

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai i'm too stupid to make the necessary cancellations happen, sorry :-(

Comment: @tired What cancellation are you talking about?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai the denominator has an infinite number of zeros in the upper half plane. we have to show that they cancel except the one at $x=i \pi$  and at $x=\infty $(and they do numerically)

Comment: @tired, what are the other zeros ? I only see $\pm \pi i $ . How to find all the zeros  ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai they are given in terms of LambertW-function...you can use mathematica to find them

Comment: see @robjohn's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @tired, wolfram wasn't able to find all the zeros. What code for mathematica ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai
For example:
Reduce[Exp[z]-z+1==I Pi,z]

Comment: @tired, one last concern. Why would we consider the residue at infinity ? Apparently the evaluations only depend on the singularity at $\pi i $.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai because apparently the residue at $x=\pi$ gives only one part of the correct solution. so what else could be the missing contribution

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai because apparently the residue at $x=\pi$ gives only one part of the correct solution. so what else could be the missing contribution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58979/discussion-between-zaid-alyafeai-and-tired).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Some integrals**

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_0 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{dz\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = {1\over2}}$$
Roots of the denominator can be defined from the system
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
\left(e^x\cos y - x + 1 + ie^x\sin y - iy\right)^2 + \pi^2 = 0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
\left(e^x\cos y - x + 1\right)^2 - \left(e^x\sin y - y\right)^2 + \pi^2 = 0\\
\left(e^x\cos y - x + 1\right)\left(e^x\sin y - y\right) = 0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
e^x\cos y = x - 1\\
\left|e^x\sin y - y\right| = \pi,
\end{cases}$$
with the solutions $z=\pm\pi i$ (see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ce%5Ex%20sin%20y%20-%20y%7C%20%3D%20pi,%20%20e%5Ex%20cos%20y%20%3D%20x%20-%201)).

So, 
$$I_0 = 2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}_{z=\pi i}{1\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = 2\pi i\lim_{z\to\pi i}{1\over2\left(e^z-z+1\right)\left(e^z-1\right)} = {1\over2}.$$

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_1 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{dz\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = {2\over3}}$$
Roots of the denominator can be defined from the system
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
\left(e^x\cos y + x + 1 + ie^x\sin y + iy\right)^2 + \pi^2 = 0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
\left(e^x\cos y + x + 1\right)^2 - \left(e^x\sin y + y\right)^2 + \pi^2 = 0\\
\left(e^x\cos y + x + 1\right)\left(e^x\sin y + y\right) = 0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
z=x+iy\\
e^x\cos y + x + 1 = 0\\
\left|e^x\sin y + y\right| = \pi,
\end{cases}$$
with the solutions $z=\pm\pi i$ (see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ce%5Ex%20sin%20y%20%2B%20y%7C%20%3D%20pi,%20%20e%5Ex%20cos%20y%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%20%3D%200,%20y%5Cin(-4,4))).

Note that the point $z=\pi i$ is a second-order pole, so
$$I_1 = 2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}_{z=\pi i}{1\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = 2\pi i\lim_{z\to\pi i} {d\over dz}\left({(z-\pi i)^2\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}\right) = {2\over3}.$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bz%5Cto%20pi%20i%7Dd%2Fdz((z-pi%20i)%5E2%2F((e%5Ez%2Bz%2B1)%5E2%2Bpi%5E2)))).

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_2 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^zdz\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = {1\over2}}$$

Really, 
$$I_2 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^zdz\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^z-1\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}\,dz + I_0$$
$$ = {1\over\pi}\left.\arctan{e^z-z-1\over\pi}\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} + {1\over 2} = {1\over2}.$$

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_3 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^zdz\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} = {1\over3}}$$

Similarly, 
$$I_3 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^zdz\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^z+1\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}\,dz - I_1$$
$$ = {1\over\pi}\left.\arctan{e^z+z-1\over\pi}\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - {2\over 3} = {1\over3}.$$

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_4 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{2z(e^z+1)^2\over\left(\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)\left(\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)}\,dx = 0}$$

Really,
$$I_4 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{2z(e^z+1)^2\over\left(\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)\left(\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)}\,dx$$
$$= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^z+1\over2}\left({1\over\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2} - {1\over\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2}\right)\,dx$$
$$= {I_2+I_0-I_3-I_1\over2} = {1\over2}\left({1\over2}+{1\over2}-{2\over3}-{1\over3}\right) = 0.$$

- Let us prove that

$$\boxed{I_5 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{2ze^z(e^z+1)^2\over\left(\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)\left(\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)}\,dx =
 1}$$

The denominator is
$$D(z) = \left(\left(e^z+1\right)^2+z^2
+\pi^2 - 2z\left(e^z+1\right)\right) \left(\left(e^z+1\right)^2+z^2+\pi^2 + 2z\left(e^z+1\right)\right)$$
$$= \left(\left(e^z+1\right)^2+z^2+\pi^2\right)^2 - 4z^2\left(e^z+1\right)^2,$$
$$D'(z) = 4\left(e^z+z+1\right)\left(\left(e^z+1\right)^2+z^2+\pi^2\right) -8z\left(e^z+1\right)\left(e^z+z+1\right)$$
$$=4\left(e^z+z+1\right)\left(\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)$$

The point $z=\pi i\ $ is the simple pole. So,

$$I_5 = 2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}_{z=\pi i}{2ze^z(e^z+1)^2\over\left(\left(e^z-z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)\left(\left(e^z+z+1\right)^2+\pi^2\right)}$$ 
$$ = 2\pi i\,\lim_{z\to\pi i}{2ze^z(e^z+1)^2\over D'(z)} = 1.$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim(z+to+pi+i)+(2ze%5Ez(e%5Ez%2B1)%2F((e%5Ez%2Bz%2B1)((e%5Ez-z%2B1)%5E2%2Bpi%5E2))))

**Final calculations**

$$I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{ke^x\pm1\over \pi^2+(e^x-x+1)}\cdot{(e^x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(e^x+x+1)^2}\cdot 2x \mathrm dx$$
$$= kI_5\pm I_4 = k.$$

Finally,
$$\boxed{\boxed{I = k}}$$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Excellent here goes the (+1) .

Answer (score 13):

First note that considering

$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{(ke^x\pm1)\over \pi^2+(e^x-x+1)^2}\cdot{(e^x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(e^x+x+1)^2}\cdot 2x \mathrm dx$$

Let $x \to \log(x)$

$$F(k)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{(kx\pm1) \over \pi^2+(x-\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot{(x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(x+\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot \frac{2\log(x)}{x} \mathrm dx = k$$

By separating the integrals note that

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{1 \over \pi^2+(x-\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot{(x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(x+\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot \frac{2\log(x)}{x} \mathrm dx=0$$

I could prove it numerically using Matlab. Hence I only show

> $$I_2=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\log(x) \over \pi^2+(x-\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot{(x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(x+\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

Consider the function

$$f(z) = \frac{(z-1)^2}{(1-(z+\log z))(1-(z-\log(z))}$$

Integrated around a key-hole contour around the principle branch of the logarithm

$$\log(z) = \log|z|+i\mathrm{Arg}(z)$$

Hence the contour

[image]

By taking the limits the smaller circle and the bigger one go to zero hence

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{(x-1)^2}{(1-(x+\log|x|+i\pi ))(1-(x-\log|x|-i\pi)}dx+\int_{0}^{-\infty}\frac{(x-1)^2}{(1-(x+\log|x|-i\pi ))(1-(x-\log|x|+i\pi)}dx = 2\pi i\mathrm{Res}(f,1)$$

Convert to the positive limit

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)^2}{(1+x-\log x-i\pi )(1+x+\log x+i\pi)}-\frac{(x+1)^2}{(1+x-\log x+i\pi )(1+x+\log x-i\pi)}dx = 2\pi i\mathrm{Res}(f,1)$$

This magically reduces to our integral

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{4\pi \,i \log(x) \over \pi^2+(x-\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot{(x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(x+\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot \mathrm dx = 2\pi i\mathrm{Res}(f,1)$$

Note that

$$\mathrm{Res}(f,1) = \lim_{z \to 1}\frac{(z-1)^3}{(1-(z+\log z))(1-(z-\log(z))} = 1$$

Hence we finally get our result

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\log(x) \over \pi^2+(x-\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot{(x+1)^2\over \pi^2+(x+\log(x)+1)^2}\cdot \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

Using the same approach we could show

> $$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{dx}{(e^x-x+1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Aren't you missing an ${i}$ in your definition of complex logarithm?

Comment: @Dmoreno, yesss, thanks.